# SharePoint 2010 Farm Setup : Virtualize the SQL Server 2008 or NOT?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, farm-setup

2 years back when I was working on SharePoint 2007 , virtualization of SQL Server was not recommend due to performance and clustering issues. When it comes to SharePoint 2010 , I see most of the MVPs support SQL Server Virtualization. I could catch up with the latest advancements of the virtulazation so I would like to know the your opinion and also answers for following queries.

- Are the performance and clustering issues resolved (I/O speed..etc) ,
  If yes, what special instructions do we have to follow ( dedicated
  H/W , I/O benchmarks.. etc)
- Known Issues when we go this option
- This farm is decidated to host Internet sites with user base around
  100K (anonymous mostly) , So do we have any special considerations
  to follow?

Any size of feedback is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as your VM infrastructure is good enough to support the memory, CPU, and data throughput required for your farm, you can virtualized the SQL server without sacrificing performance.  You need to ensure your VM farm has enough available resources to dedicate to the SQL server and not be overloaded with other VMs taking RAM away from the SQL VM. Also, fast SAN storage is a must. SQL will require a lot of disk reads and writes, so the data storage infrastructure needs to be able to handle it.

With all of that said, I have a SQL cluster with 32 gb ram each on VMs that is sufficient for a public website with 1M+ hits per month.